# RGB bias lighting with HDMI passthru for ultrawide monitor

Tags: monitors, hdmi

I'm looking into bias lighting for behind my monitor. I would prefer a device that has HDMI passthru since I plug in a few different devices (laptop, Nintendo Switch, etc.). The monitor is 2560x1080. I really don't like the idea of camera-based bias lighting.

I found [this company](https://lightpack.tv/) which looks pretty good, but I don't know if their "HD" device works with that aspect ratio/resolution. Their support contact also doesn't seem to like replying (both the form and email).

To summarize:

- RGB Bias lighting kit
- HDMI passthru
- support for 2560x1080 resolution

Comment: Yes, reviews on Amazon https://www.amazon.com/Lightpack-backlight-accessories-Matching-backlighting/product-reviews/B00LFW1P6U?pageNumber=4  can be critical of their lack of responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

No alternative found using HDMI pass-through.

A camera-based alternative is [Ambivision](https://ambivision.tv/shop/) (their [Kickstarter campaign](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ambivision-standalone-ambient-lighting-device#/)). Their email is [support@ambivision.tv](http://mailto:support@ambivision.tv); their Skype is labteam.innovations .

A computer-only alternative is [AmbiLED HD](https://flytron.com/electronic-parts/284-ambiled-hd-ambient-light-kit-for-computer-monitors.html) (their [Kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1410893208/ambiled-hd-high-definition-ambient-light)) but it does not use HDMI passthrough.

Comment: Where did you see that Ambivision doesn't use cameras? Their website directly states they use a 180--degree fisheye camera. I also already know how Stack Exchange works